# Where does netifaces extract to?

Tags: python, c#, module, python-netifaces

I am trying to install the netifaces module and was able to run the `tar xvzf netifaces-0.11.0.tar.gz`  command. It looks like it extracted all the folders it needed too but I dont see them in my download folder or in my site-packages under my python folder which is where I saw everything should go to be imported in python.

I ask because to run the install it says on their page to `cd` to the folder it extracted and then run the setup.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see what is inside tar.gz. here is a guide https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/

also, didn't you forget about "-" ?
`tar -xvzf netifaces-0.11.0.tar.gz`

Comment: I did forget sorry but thank you for pointing that out. I was getting frustrated because it showed like it was extracting but apparently was not so I was focused on finding the extracted files.